# Xperia Facebook messenger acting strange

Tags: facebook, sony-xperia

My sony xperia xa1 decvice keeps reinstalling why looks like a dated version of Facebook and messenger..have I been hacked?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Have you been hacked?  No.

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me too.
Just reinstall Messenger again
It worked for me
I hope it will work for you too

Comment: Done, I will accept coincidence. I have deleted my former comments.